SQL Server analysis cube deployment error
I have a deployment error in Visual Studio trying to deploy a cube to SQL Server Analysis Services. I ensured in the cube solution explorer properties that the server name matches the SQL Server  name and it is running as I can see in SQL Server Configuration Manager.
The errors I am getting are:

OutputStringNoPump must be called on the UI thread


The server could not be contacted

I tried reinstalling the SQL Server Analysis Services, installing and using another SQL Server Analysis Services server, and I expected deployment to be successful but nothing changed.
